# array in url API request

Tags: api, url, url-parameters

I have to call an API from my program. The API is on a remote server and i have to give the paramaters trough an url.

the parameters i have to give are the following :

```
    apikey = khreer932jkee982jksj
    method = method.mymethod
    username = myusername
    type = 234
    data{
        group{              
                id = 593
                groupleader = groupleadername 
                groupmembers {
                        1 = groupmemberone,
                        2 = groupmembertwo
                }
                descr = testgroup
        }
      created = datetimestamp
      modified = datetimestamp
    }
```

The first part of the data i know how to pass it trough url.

```
server.myserver.nl/api/?method=method.mymethod&apikey=khreer932jkee982jksj&username=myusername&type=234
```

After this i'm puzzled and i don't know how to pass the data.
I can't make any modifications to the receiving side of the api, because i don't have control of it

please help.

Comment: Most likely you need to send all this as POST data. Without any knowledge of the web service, it's not possible to help you more.

Comment: found the answer, forgot i still had the question open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer i had to send it this way

```
server.myserver.nl/api/?method=method.mymethod&apikey=khreer932jkee982jksj&username=myusername&type=234&data[group][id]=593&data[group][groupleader]=groupleadername&data[group][groupmembers][]=groupmemberone&data[group][groupmembers][]=groupmembertwo&data[group][descr]=testgroup
```